# iniciar un intervalo en una funcion y terminarlo en otra funcion

Tags: javascript

quiero que con onmouseenter llamo una funcion que tiene un setInterval para llamar otra funcion y con onmouseout quiero romper el setInterval anterior aqui un ejemplo de lo que intente hacer

```
<div id="insertar" class="contenedor-imagen" onmouseenter="funcion1()" onmouseout="funcion2()">

function funcion1() {
    var t = 0;
    var llamado = setInterval(
        function(){
            t++;
            if (t === 1) clearInterval(llamado);
            llamarOtra();
        },2000
    )
}
function llamarOtra{}
function funcion2() {
    clearInterval(llamado);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay otras alternativas; voy a optar por usar una *closure*, de modo que mantengamos todo el proceso controlado y oculto a funciones externas.

Para ello, vamos a cambiar un poco tu `html`, quitando el evento `onmouseout`:

```
<div id="insertar" class="contenedor-imagen" onmouseenter="funcion1()">
```

Y modificamos un poco también tu función `funcion1( )`, de forma que sea desde ahí desde donde asignemos la función a ejecutar en el evento `onmouseout`:

```
function funcion1( ) {
  var t = 0;
  var llamado = setInterval( function( ) {
    t++;
    if( t === 1 ) clearMouseOut( );
  }, 2000 );

  document.getElementById( 'insertar' ).onmouseout = clearMouseOut;
  llamarOtra( );

  function clearMouseOut( ) {
    clearInterval( llamado );
    delete ( document.getElementById( 'insertar' ) ).onmouseout;
  }
}
```

Comment: pues me sirvio aunque sacaste la función llamar otra de función1 y lo que necesitaba era que esa funcion se llamara cuando el mouse pasara por el div,asi que puse llamarOtra dentro de funcion1

Comment: En tu código la llamabas en el *timeout*, y me basé en eso. Es trivial, editado y arreglado :-)

Comment: me sirvió gracias